# How to write a objectives section in undergraduate thesis?

Tags: thesis, undergraduate, statistics

I'm writting my undergraduate statistical thesis proposal. I wrote directly and clearly what I intend to do in my project. However the objectives section was very small, only 6 lines. It would be appropriate to give details of the objectives, even though they already being clear from the introduction?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between what you intend to do and what you hope to achieve or learn. The doing part is about the procedure you expect to follow.  The objectives part is about what you hope to achieve or learn from it.